# Poweredge RAID Monitoring and Debian

Tags: debian, raid, hardware-raid

What tools do you use to monitor hardware RAID Status on Dell Poweredge 2950 (II and III, perc)? I run Debian. I've used a "debianized" version of dell openmanage in the past. I'm looking for a lightweight solution and (if possible) something "debian packaged".

Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As womble said, grab the OMSA packages from [that blog post](http://sadsoftware.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/installing-dell-omsa-and-snmp-in-ubuntu.html) and use NRPE to call [check_openmanage](http://folk.uio.no/trondham/software/check_openmanage.html).

This'll give you good coverage over all the Dell hardware in your box (including the RAID array(s))

Answer (score 1):

We run OMSA on all our Dell servers, and then have NRPE plugins to query that information to generate results for Nagios to process, graph, alert on, etc.

Comment: I can't find that package, except on the Dell website. Perhaps you know what the name of the package is?

Comment: What package?  OMSA?  Someone's packaged it for Debian at http://sadsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/08/installing-dell-omsa-and-snmp-in-ubuntu.html  The rest is all open source and already in Debian.

Answer (score 1):

not debian packaged..

i use ipmi over lan to read drac logs. i run:

```
ipmitool -L USER -H 10.1.2.3 -U ipmi_username -P password sel elist last 10
```

this gives me last 10 log messages. if there is something there - probably strange stuff has occurred [ memory errors, redundant psu died etc ]

i run locally MegaCLI to query for raid status. it requires root privileges so i have cron job that executes:

```
./MegaCli -AdpAllInfo -aALL|grep -v "Current Time"  >> current.txt
./MegaCli -PDList -aALL   >> current.txt
./MegaCli AdpBbuCmd -aAll|grep "Aalarm"|grep -v "^Remaining" >> current.txt
./MegaCli -LDInfo -Lall -aALL >> current.txt
```

while nagios nrpe plugin just compares current.txt with expected.txt and alerts if they dont match.

you can google for megacli or download it from lsi webpage.

Answer (score 0):

OMSA works with debian, with a bit of tweaking, and it's not *that* heavy

on the other hand you can set up linux native tools, or the additional packages like nagios, munin etc.

Comment: not *that* heavy? the .deb is 90Mb! You mentioned native tools - what are there?

Comment: by heavy I meant the amount of tweaking required, not the file size. And by native I mean nagios plugins and scripts utilizing `megacli`